# Is dangerous bend a classical symbol in TeX?

Tags: symbols

In *TeXbook*, there's such a symbol,[image]. Is this a classical symbol in TeX? I remembered seeing this somewhere else, and it was also a handout or book produced by LaTeX. If so, is there any method to input this apart from inserting it as a picture?

Comment: Oddly enough this one can't be found in e.g. deTeXify ([How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara)), but then this one takes 4 strokes to draw so maybe I just didn't use the correct order.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See page 188 of [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) : `manfnt` package, `\dbend`.

Edit: suggested the reversed symbol. Corrected thanks to @Teepeemm.

Comment: @Teepeemm You're right. I corrected my answer, thanks.